Environment variable not recognised in python or terminal but I can see it in system properties
I am trying to set an openai key to use the ChatGPT api. I did so using the following command in the terminal:
setx OPENAI_API_KEY "api_key_text"`

After this, if I go to the list of environmental variables from system properties, (i.e. "edit the system environmental variables" from control panel) then I can see the new env variable and it looks like it has worked fine. However, if I go to python (using Jupyter notebook if that is relevant) and type:
import os

api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
print(api_key)

then I get the answer "None". Also, it doesn't show up typing SET in terminal. Given that I can see it in systems properties, why can Python not find it?
Any help appreciated.

Did you set the key after starting the notebook kernel? Restart the kernel and possibly try again after restarting the PC.

wat do u get with: api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")

I believe you can check if the environment variable has been properly set by typing
echo $env:OPENAI_API_KEY

Your command to set an environment variable sounds about right, but then you'd hit a wall if your jupyter session existed prior to setting the variable.
You can also try to use Set-Variable instead of setx if you want to have it active for the current shell session:
set OPENAI_API_KEY="somevalue"

In the end, I'd try restarting the notebook to refresh the session. Let us know how this goes !
